# RarozEngine deny to use Namespace while generating page

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, razorengine

Good afternoon.
In my solution I use RazorEngine library, to generate dynamic pages received from the database.

Ordinary users can edit pages (views) in his office.

*(Used to generate PDF files, DOC files, and MasterPage their personal pages).*

Example:

```
<p>Total to pay: @Model["PAYABLE"] @Model["CURRENCY"]</p>
```

Or:

```
@foreach(string link in Model.StylesLinks){
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="@link" />
}
```

All functionality is implemented, but there was one big hole in the system. 
Now any user can execute any code.

For example, you can easily display the list of ConnectionStrings:

```
@foreach (System.Configuration.ConnectionStringSettings conn in 
                    System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings)
{
    @:@conn.ConnectionString<br/>
}
```

Then, using this ConnectionStrings, you can connect to the database and do anything.

**Question**: How can I disable using namespace, such as "System"?

---

Simply replace the word "System" in text is not suitable. You can always get the class simply by name. (+ There are many ways to do this)

```
Type sys = Type.GetType("Sys" + "tem.Configuration.ConfigurationManager");
```

Comment: I think you need to create a sandbox: How to: Run Partially Trusted Code in a Sandbox: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb763046%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Answer (score 1):

VahidN is correct: You should run this code in a sandbox.

RazorEngine allows you to do just that with the Isolation API, which is documented [here](https://antaris.github.io/RazorEngine/Isolation.html).
Basically you need to tell RazorEngine how you want to create the AppDomain (and what permissions to use) and then use the `Isolated*` version of the RazorEngine API.
Note that <3.5.0 version are not able to run within AppDomains that do not have full trust. 3.5.0 (currently beta) should work though.

Disclaimer: I contributed some bug-fixes in that area to RazorEngine.